# Why I'm getting this issue in my astro.build project

Tags: javascript, html, astrojs, unexpected-token

Why I'm getting this error all the time Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
D:/workspace/vixen/src/pages/home.astro:35:6: ERROR: Unterminated regular expression
at failureErrorWithLog (D:\workspace\vixen\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1651:15)
[My Astro code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3RUC.jpg)
[Error] [`unexpected '>'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PHmv.jpg)

Comment: It is hard to know without more context

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code and please format your question with markdown...

Comment: Try only returning 1 HTML element from your function. So put `<></>` around all HTML.

Comment: Is the "component script" part of your astro page set up to support jsx?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please follow the following to improve your question and get a better help from community: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask